# What happened to moderator meetings?

Tags: discussion, moderators

[Oli](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/449/oli), [moderator of Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators), posted this post on January 4, 2014: [Mod Meeting 2014-01-04: "On Meetings"](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7995)

Did moderators have any similar meetings after the one which was held on January 4, 2014?

If no, what happened to the moderator meetings? Are they no longer happening?

If they are no longer happening, what was the reason for stopping such meetings?

I would love to hear the moderators' views.

Comment: Considering it was the first one, probably it wasn't as useful as imagined. Odd to see "meetings" plural when there only ever was this one meeting.

Comment: @muru I thought that the mod meetings happened but weren't documented in Ask Ubuntu Meta.

Comment: A few days after that there was https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8026/158442 and then no more mention of meetings. If a meeting had happened, I'd imaginw they would have discussed that and posted a response, but since there has been nothing since, I'm going to go with "nothing happened after that".

Comment: @muru Hopefully, jokerdino might know what happened after the first meeting 

Comment: jokerdino told me there were several meetings after that. Four are bookmarked in the private chat room

Comment: @Zanna Did the mod meetings happen in "Ubuntu Moderation" or some other chatroom?

Comment: they happened there only

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I love the idea of occasional mod meetings, but I'd want them to be less formal than the one mentioned in the post you linked to. Since I have been a mod, there haven't been any such meetings and I don't recall hearing about them. However, there is a private room for Ask Ubuntu mods which is great for asynchronous discussion of whatever comes up as and when, which serves our purposes well enough, I think.

What I think would be even better than mod meetings would be an open meeting (like, maybe a monthly event in [AUGR](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) or possibly [the Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat)) for discussion of moderation stuff that might benefit from the input of diamond mods (like, rather than, though not excluding, general community moderation, for which the Downboat is already a hub).

Comment: I'm curious to know what's the name of the private chat room. If you can't share the name (as it needs to private), it's OK.

Comment: The private chat room is unexcitingly called "Ubuntu Moderation"

Comment: @RandomPerson there's nothing special about that room. Moderators can create private rooms, something usually done to discuss private moderation issues with specific users or other mods. So it's very common that a site's moderation team will make a chat room where they can discuss moderation issues. The name is arbitrary and chosen by each site's mods. But it's just a room like any other.

Comment: @terdon OK. I understood.